# Django template add 2 strings variables using 'with'

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I add 2 strings in Django template.
I want to define the image url string so I try to join 2 strings. Product is my model and 'image' is its attribute.

```
{% with image='product/img/'+product.image %}
<img src="{% static image %}" style="width:600px; height:230px; margin:50 0 50 0">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Please add `product` model definition to your question.

Comment: Why do you store images which are not static in the static directory?

Comment: can you remove the with? `<img src="product/img/{% static image %}" style="width:600px; height:230px; margin:50 0 50 0">`